# Creators Update incompatible with AllocationPreference MemTopDown?

Tags: windows-10-v1703

for testing my own application for compatibility with LargeAddressAware (LAA) i have set the `AllocationPreference` of the windows "Memory Management" to MEM_TOP_DOWN as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22745579

"MemTopDown.reg" (requires windows reboot):

```
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management]
"AllocationPreference"=dword:00100000
```

--

on my test environment i have now upgraded to Windows 10 Version 1703 (Creators Update).

by coincidence i have noticed that other 32bit applications that also are LAA enabled are now crashing. for example:

- firefox 53.0
- chrome 58.0.3029.81
- adobe acrobat reader dc 17.009.20044
- irfanview 4.44
- xmind 8 (3.7.1.201612151837)
- ms excel 16.0.4522.1000
- ms powerpoint 16.0.4266.1001

those type of crashes all are pointing to:

```
Faulting module name: CoreMessaging.dll, version: 10.0.15063.0
```

--

**question:**
is there any known bug with windows 10 (version 1703) and the `AllocationPreference` switch?

--

edit:
to address the initial comments: this question is about a test environment with the `AllocationPreference` registry switch enabled - which is *not* there by default! it's a custom switch to better identify application bugs with memory addresses.
but here it seems to be a bug with the windows OS itself: it seems that **any** 32bit application with LAA enabled would crash *in case* the MemTopDown switch is set.

the symptom is not observed on earlier service pack levels of windows 10.
the symptom is not observed on other versions such as windows 7.

--

edit2:
a note to all those initial "comments": i have now added the registry switch to this question.
just add it to your system, reboot, and see all LAA 32bit applications crash ...
to revert back simply remove that registry entry, again.

--

edit3:
now adding a screenshot from my WER crash dumps (windows error reporting) on http://sysdev.microsoft.com/
it is pointing to "microsoft::coreui::dispatch::useradapter_handledispatchnotifymessage":

[image]

Comment: I use those programs and have not had issues with them in Creators Update. I'm guessing your problems are local/unique and not systemic to the update itself.

Comment: for me they work. VS2017 is also Large Adress aware ad works fine in 1703 VM

Comment: Have you tried it on more than one computer with Windows 1703? (to determine if it's just your computer or not).

Comment: "the symptom is not observed on earlier service pack levels of windows 10." - If you revert back to 1607 on the same system does this behavior exhbit itself?

Comment: You are sure this worked for you before? My logic says top-memory shouldn't work for 32-bit DLLs if the computer has more than 4GB of RAM, because they cannot handle being loaded that high up in RAM.

Comment: share a full crash dump of Firefox (best would be a nightly build crash, because it has better debug options).

Comment: I've submitted it to Microsoft last week but haven't got any status update.

Comment: as I already said, I've reported it, but never got a reply what they will do regarding to the issue. report it also via feedback hub app

Comment: again, create a feedback entry in feedback hub app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now *fixed* with **cumulative update KB4025342** (2017-07-11) - or later.

It carries the version number `10.0.15063.483`.

Comment: nice to hear that they fixed it now.